# What is the method signature of a lambda that receives lambda InvokeInput?

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I'd like to get my two lambdas to communicate with each other. Lambda A uses InvokeInput, passing Payload as used in the example here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/go/example_code/lambda/aws-go-sdk-lambda-example-run-function.go

However, the example doesn't show the receiving end i.e Lambda B. I'm trying to access `Payload`, so I've tried a handler with the method signatures:

```
func Handler(ctx context.Context, lambdaInput messages.InvokeRequest) (api.Response, error)
```

as well as

```
func Handler(ctx context.Context, lambdaInput lambda.InvokeInput) (api.Response, error)
```

When calling `lambdaInput.Payload` on the former it returns `[]` despite what's being sent as a payload.

I am unable to find the documentation on this, does anyone know the proper signature that I should be using?

Answer (score 2):

From AWS docuentation:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-handler-types.html

> The following lists valid handler signatures. TIn and TOut represent types compatible with the encoding/json standard library. For more information, see func Unmarshal to learn how these types are deserialized.

```
func ()
func () error
func (TIn), error
func () (TOut, error)
func (context.Context) error
func (context.Context, TIn) error
func (context.Context) (TOut, error)
func (context.Context, TIn) (TOut, error)
```

So it depends on what is in your payload. AWS will try to deserialize your data and match it with the `TIn` parameter in your function. There are already some types that represent AWS Event types, but in your case you should write your own struct. Check the link for some examples.